# jQuery Animation - not working when called thro a function

Tags: jquery-animate

My objective is to create a generic function for animation which would require to pass in parameters, assuming the function can be used for animating any elements.

I started with simple animation that wouldn't require passing parameters and it seems to work fine. Here is the code and [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5v86F/7/)

```
<div id="outer" class="box">
    <div id="inner" class="box"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="animate" value="Animate"/>​     
​$("#inner").animate({left: '+=300', top: '+=300'}, 1000);​
```

BUT its not working when I try to write a genric function... [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5v86F/18/)

```
$("#animate").Click(function(){
    diagonalAnimation("inner");
});

function diagonalAnimation(e){
$('"#'+e+'"').animate({left: '+=300', top: '+=300'}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/5v86F/81/ )

```
<div id="outer" class="box">
    <div id="inner" class="box"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="animate" value="Animate" onclick="animate('inner')"/>

<script>
    function animate( item )
    {
         $( "#" + item ).animate({left: '+=300', top: '+=300'}, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: its not a generic function. By doing as you said, I will be able to animate only element with id = "inner"

Comment: it is generic, just set the item you want to animate as the value of the button... <input type="button" id="animate" value="generic item to anmiate" />

Comment: @ Payne -- Thanks, but what if I want to use animate function on different elements. How would I reuse that function?

Comment: My objective is to pass the element to animate as an argument of the animation function

Comment: @Priya i'm not entirely sure what you're asking.. i edited the above code, there are now 2 buttons that control and animate 2 different boxes..

Comment: @Payne - I want the button to display Animate. Thats a requirement. I can't display any other value in the button

Comment: Another requirement is to pass the element as an argument of the Animation function. Your code will work fine. But won't solve my requirements

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10398/discussion-between-priya-and-jonathan-payne)

Comment: it still has a problem..when "animate" button is clicked twice, the inner box keeps moving down

Comment: You only want to be able to click and move it once? What should it do on the second click?